# SQLite: Get Total/Sum of Column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite and am trying to return the total of one column `buy_price` in the column `TOTAL` while at the same time returning all of the data. I do not want/need to group the data as I need to have the data in each returned row.

```
id    date       pool_name    pool_id    buy_price  TOTAL
 1    09/01/12   azp          5          20
 2    09/02/12   mmp          6          10
 3    09/03/12   pbp          4          5
 4    09/04/12   azp          7          20
 5    09/05/12   nyp          8          5             60
```

When I include something like  `SUM(buy_price) as TOTAL` it only returns one row. I need all rows returned along with the total of all `buy_price` entries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you are looking for:

```
select id,
  dt,
  pool_name,
  pool_id,
  buy_price,
  (select sum(buy_price) from yourtable) total
from yourtable
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/13cd1/1)

Comment: Thanks. This is close, however for some reason it is returning double the sum, i.e. 120 instead of 60. Also, it's listed in every row, not that it's a big deal. I thought there was a way using COALESCE to have it returned just once (I am NO SQL expert so I very well could be wrong) Thanks!!!

Comment: @user1650361 can you create a sqlfiddle with some additional sample data?  Based on the limited data you provided it appears to be working.

Comment: This works. Issue with my SQL statement was causing the wrong data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from yourtable
union
select 'Total',
  ' ',
  ' ',
  ' ',
  sum(buy_price)
from yourtable
```

you can add a row on the bottom like this instead of adding a new column...